# Understanding unused typedef of empty inherited class

Tags: c++, inheritance, typedef

I'm just trying to understand some tutorial code I'm going through.  I'm trying to learn some Dx11 code and the tutorial I'm going through has classes that are designed as event details to be passed to functions when an event occurs, e.g. a mouse button being pressed.  There's an empty base class EventArgs defined as follows:

```
class EventArgs
{
public:
    EventArgs() {};
}
```

Which is the inherited by other event like classes.  So for example they have a key pressed event args class as follows:

```
class KeyEventArgs : public EventArgs
{
public:
    typedef EventArgs base;
    KeyEventArgs(/**/)
    { }

    // Rest of the class
}
```

I understand the premise that all the events are inheriting a base to say "they are an event type" but I don't understand the typedef base which is in every event class but isn't used by them directly.  It seems as if a function that takes a KeyEventArgs parameter uses this base typedef to pass the event on to it's own base class but I don't understand how that works.  The example they give is:

```
class Game
{
    virtual void onKeyRelease(KeyEventArgs &e);
}

class Tutorial : public Game
{
    void onKeyRelease(KeyEventArgs &e) 
    {
        base::onKeyRelease(e);
        /* Above calls Game::onKeyRelease(e) */
    }
}
```

If anyone could shed any light on why/how the above works I'd be very grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `Game` have a `base` member typedef too?

Comment: If that's the example, it's missing `typedef Game base;` in the `Tutorial` class.

Comment: ouch... no virtual destructor

Comment: Yeah I made a mistake and missed the typedef Game base, my bad.  Makes a lot more sense now.  The virtual destructor is there, just snipped it out of the example to keep the code short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word `base` is not a keyword so in the `class Tutorial` example, the line  `base::onKeyRelease(e);` will not compile. Now, if you saw it somewhere and it does compile, you must know that it must be define by a [`typedef`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) or a [`using`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) statement somewhere.

The purpose of the using such a `typedef` is to add another level of abstraction to help people change code safely. Considering the Tutorial example you could just as well write `Game::onKeyRelease(e);` Let's consider the following example:

```
class Game
{
    virtual void onKeyRelease(KeyEventArgs &e);
}
class AwsomeGame : public Game
{
    virtual void onKeyRelease(KeyEventArgs &e);
}

class Tutorial : public Game
{
    typedef Game base;

    void onKeyRelease(KeyEventArgs &e) 
    {
        base::onKeyRelease(e);
        //equivalent to Game::onKeyRelease(e);
    }
}
```

If you change Tutorial base class from `Game` to `AwsomeGame` and the `typedef` also you have successfully changed the code without any bad side effects.

Not using a `typedef` would force you to write explicit calls to `Game`, and when the base class changes, you will have to change it in all the places you have used it. Now, if you consider the above example and you change `Game` to `AwsomeGame` without changing the `typedef` the code is valid, but you might run into a logical error later:

```
class Tutorial : public AwsomeGame //,public Game
{

    void onKeyRelease(KeyEventArgs &e) 
    {
        Game::onKeyRelease(e);
        //code is valid, but you probably want AwsomeGame::onKeyRelease(e); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah of course, yeah I've missed the typedef Game base in tutorial.h d'oh.  Thanks for the explanation though, makes sense when you think about the potential name changes.  Neat little trick.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing magic here. Some other languages will provide a `base`, or similar, keyword to access the base class.

Obviously the programmers here like that, and simulate this by providing their own `base`. They could very well have written

```
class Tutorial : public Game
{
    void onKeyRelease(KeyEventArgs &e) 
    {
        Game::onKeyRelease(e);
       /* Above calls Game::onKeyRelease(e) */
    }
}
```

and avoided confusion (and a comment on what the code does).